# failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

Tags: grub2, uefi, grub-efi

I fresh installed Kubuntu 16.10 and now it doesn't seem to want to boot. I get 2 messages when trying to boot.

```
failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi - device error
failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi - device error
```

Here is my boot info summary: http://paste2.org/UOfjLy6O

Comment: Have you tried booting a liveCD and running `boot-repair`?

Comment: twice. yes thats how i got the boot summary. I'm using a live usb as the main os since it wont boot any other way.